# ¿Como hago inserciones dinámicas en base al tamaño de un arreglo?

Tags: java, jsp

Va de nuevo, tengo un arreglo:
    String[ ] cosa1 = {3,4};
Y esos numeros quiero insertarlos, cuando SEGUN YO hago el for MIDIENDO el arreglo para iterar las veces que voy a INSERTAR en este caso 2, preparo el siguiente codigo:

```
for(int i  = 0; i < cosa1.length; i++){
                cosaUnoModel.setProp_id(request.getParameter("id_propiedad").toString());
                cosaUnoModel.setCosa_id(cosa1[i]);
                cosaUnoModel.setPpc_status("1");
                String id_cosa = cosaUnoDao.addPropCosaModel(cosaUnoModel);
            }
```

Pero el arreglo en esta parte `cosaUnoModel.setCosa_id(cosa1[i]);` en vez de insertar `cosaUnoModel.setCosa_id(4)` porque era el primer numero (la primera iteracion del for) inserta `cosaUnoModel.setCosa_id(4,3)` y por esa razon mi query sale mal -> `INSERT INTO prop_cosa  ( prop_id,cosa_id,ppc_status,ppc_update) VALUES (33,4,3,1,now());`

Comment: No entiendo tu problema concreto. Lo primero que veo es que, según indicas, se manda a ejecutar el query `INSERT INTO prop_cosa  (prop_id,cosa_id,ppc_status,ppc_update) VALUES (33,4,3,1,now());`, el cual está mal armado porque tienes 4 columnas en el insert pero le mandas 5 valores. Desde allí ya tienes un grave problema.

Comment: Mi arreglo contiene esto String[ ] cosa1 = {4,3};
cuando hago el for para insertar SEGUN YO de manera dinamica, 
for(int i  = 0; i < cosa1.length; i++){                cosaUnoModel.setProp_id(request.getParameter("id_propiedad").toString());
cosaUnoModel.setCosa_id(cosa1[i]);
                cosaUnoModel.setPpc_status("1");
                String id_cosa = cosaUnoDao.addPropCosaModel(cosaUnoModel);
            } no me pasa 1 dato, sino los 2 y por eso arma despues el query mal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo visto, el valor de `request.getParameter("cosa1")` es la cadena con los elementos concatentados `"4,3"`, por ello tu problema. Debes separar cada subcadena de la cadena principal en base a la coma:

```
String[] cosa1 = request.getParameter("cosa1").toString().split(",");
```

Además de esto, tienes un problema mayor. Si dices que el query generado es:

```
INSERT INTO prop_cosa (prop_id,cosa_id,ppc_status,ppc_update) VALUES (33,4,3,1,now())
```

Signfica que estás armando el query concatenando cadenas, lo cual es altamente peligroso. En lugar de esto, sería mejor si implementaras tu query con soporte de parámetros y usando `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Genial tienes un grado alto de comprensión, efectivamente ese era el problema, ya implemente y verifique que en efecto, enviaba una cadena concatenada, mi duda es, la función .split(","); funciona para? Pero esa ya es tarea mía, ya la investigo por mi cuenta, muchas gracias, siempre el apoyo de ustedes es bueno.